# tunnelling and normal http server on the same server

Tags: http-tunneling, localtunnel

I am using go-http-tunnel for local tunneling. My server domain is let's say xyz.com, clients connect to *.xyz.com.

What I want to achieve is use xyz.com for normal apache server and subdomain.xyz.com for tunneling.(I want to achive it using only ports 80 and 443)